# how to make text-area like in google colab?

Tags: javascript, php, textarea, google-colaboratory

output is going and going on line by line and consuming my pc's resource.[see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oefAx.png)
I want to only leave last 50 lines of code while running, no previous output needed.
PLease HELP

```
<?php
$path=$_GET['path'].'/%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s';
$link=$_GET['link'];
$link1="d: && cd 1project && youtube-dl.exe -o \"$path\" -v \"$link\" 2>&1";
while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$cmd=$link1;
$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
echo '<pre id="CON">';
while (!feof($proc))
{
    echo fread($proc, 4096);
    //echo fread($proc);
    @ flush();
    sleep(5);
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: The `@` error supressor? If you are getting errors it is better to fix them than ignore them, specially when you are trying to fix other things

Comment: brother code runs successfully but i need to customize the output in browser window..
i ran cmd command and in cmd it does not print a new line every time it's progress increases, but it happens in browser.